# pdfsearch "text not recognized in pdf"

Tags: r, keyword-search

I tried to use the package "pdfsearch" to search for specific keywords in pdf file, but I get the following warnings for some documents.
I used the keyword_directory for all the pdf in the same folder, and some could generate the result but some show the warning. I have double-confirmed that the keywords could be find from all the pdf (using the adobe Ctrl-F to search).

My code is

```
key_file <- keyword_directory(paste("myfolder", sep=""),
                     keyword=c("Audit"), full_names = TRUE,
                     surround_lines = 1,
                     remove_hyphen = TRUE
                      )
```

and I got the following messages:

> Warning messages: 1: In keyword_search(files_dir[xx], keyword =
> keyword, path = TRUE,  :   text not recognized in pdf

Is there any way to fix this? Thank you :)

Comment: Hi Icwu. You have a typo in your example (no closing quote after `"myfolder`. Can you confirm this is not the source of your error?

Comment: Hi Allan, Yes it's a typo when I change the directory for clarification (not the real path). Thank you for noticing this.